# Prime factorization of a number

Tags: python-3.x, prime-factoring

I'm trying to write a program to find all the prime factors of a given number, and tried the following:

```
def factors(nr):
    i = 2
    factors = []
    while i<nr:
        if (nr%i)==0:
            factors.append(i)
            nr = nr/i
        else:
            i = i+1
    return factors
```

My idea is the following. Start with i = 2, while i < the number, check if the module of the number and i = 0. If this is the case, add i to a list, and run the algorithm again, but now with the new number. However, my algorithm doesn't work. Any idea why?

I know that several right answers are posted on the site, but I would like to know why my program is incorrect.

**Update**
So if I let the programm run for example:

factors(38), yields [2].

factors(25), yields [5].

So it stops after it has added one number to the list.

Comment: @WillNess But actually, my question has already been answered by DavidCullen

Comment: now, that you've edited, we can suggest you try your original code, e.g. with  30. does it also add only one number to the list? No. It in fact doesn't add ________ (complete the sentence). This gives you a good clue to what's wrong with your code. Being able to find it yourself got to be more illuminating, and it was enabled by you providing the test case, after all. The guidelines are there for a reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest change you can make to fix your problem is to change your `while` loop condition:

```
def factors(nr):
    i = 2
    factors = []
    while i <= nr:
        if (nr % i) == 0:
            factors.append(i)
            nr = nr / i
        else:
            i = i + 1
    return factors

print factors(8)
print factors(9)
print factors(10)
```

**Output**

```
[2, 2, 2]
[3, 3]
[2, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def ba(n):
    pfa=[]
    y=n
    for i in range(n):
        if (i!=0 and i!=1):
            while (y%i==0):
                pfa.append(i)
                y=y/i
    print(pfa)
```

Comment: It would greatly improve you code-only answer to add some explanations as to *why* and *how* it solves the problem in hand

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I wrote an explanation. I want to contribute this website, and comments like yours is more than welcome.

Comment: Also, please note that you have an indentation error. While it is pretty clear how to fix the error in this case, code posted here should be able to be copy-pasted and ran without errors

Comment: Oops!!! Yes I can see the indentation error.... from the next time I’ll keep this in mind...... and thanks for the suggestion

Comment: You know you can (and should) [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57443149/edit) your answer