# How can i sum co-prime numbers in a pair

Tags: python-3.x

I have this list

`a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

I want to find out that how many co-prime pair elements of the list add up to **sum=9**

Ex, `(1+8) = 9` , `(2+7) = 9` , `(3+6)=9` , `(4+5)=9`, `(5+4)=9` , `(6+3)=9`, `(7+2)=9` , `(8+1)=9`

**Note that i don't want (3+6) as they are prime numbers.  And i also don't want (7+2)=9 as it has already occurred (means 2,7 has been already taken in account)**

I tried this But it takes repeated values too.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
count=0
for m in a:
    for n in a:
        total=m+n
        if(total==9):
            s=str(m) + '+'+ str(n) + "="
            print(s , m+n)
            count=count+1
print("Count =" ,count)
```

The result should have count=3

Comment: 3 is a prime - 6 not so much. 2 and 5 and 7 are also primes ... why not want 3 but the others?

Comment: Also : your local variable `sum` hides the buildin `sum()` function - it is better to not use builtin fuction names.

Comment: Maybe mention:  `coprime == no single prime divides both found numbers`

Comment: I changed 'sum' to 'total'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Your mistake is in the way of doing the loops, so you repeat values.***

Try this:

```
#from math import gcd as bltin_gcd

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

count = 0


def __gcd(a, b):
    # Everything divides 0
    if (a == 0 or b == 0): return 0

    # base case
    if (a == b): return a

    # a is greater
    if (a > b):
        return __gcd(a - b, b)

    return __gcd(a, b - a)

# Only python 3
# def coprime(a, b):
#     return bltin_gcd(a, b) == 1


for i in range(0,9):
    for j in range(i+1,9):
        if __gcd(a[i], a[j]) == 1 and a[i] + a[j] == 9:
            count += 1
            print str(a[i]) + ' ' + str(a[j])

print 'Count = ' + str(count)
```

In number theory, two integers a and b are said to be relatively prime, mutually prime, or coprime if the only positive integer that divides both of them is 1. Consequently, any prime number that divides one does not divide the other. This is equivalent to their greatest common divisor being 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
for m in a:
    for n in a:
```

You are not selecting pairs by using this loops, ie. you are picking the first element in both the outer and inner loop during your first iteration.

```
if(total==9):
```

You are not checking the condition if the selected pair of numbers are `coprime`. You are only verifying the sum.

Answer (score 0):

A pythonic solution may be obtained with a one-liner:

```
from math import gcd
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

pairs = [(m,n) for m in a for n in a if n > m and m+n == 9 and gcd(m,n) == 1]
```

Result :

```
pairs --> [(1, 8), (2, 7), (4, 5)]
```

If you are sure to never, never need the pairs but only the number of pairs (as written in the OP), the most efficient solution may be:

```
count = len([1 for m in a for n in a if n > m and m+n == 9 and gcd(m,n) == 1])
```

**EDIT :** I inversed the three conditions in the `if` statement for improved benefit from lazy boolean evaluation

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this if you have something that calculates your prime factorization in python:

```
from functools import lru_cache

# cached function results for pime factorization of identical nr  
@lru_cache(maxsize=100)
def factors(nr):
    # adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43129243/7505395
    i = 2
    factors = []          
    while i <= nr:      
        if (nr % i) == 0:
            factors.append(i)
            nr = nr / i
        else:
            i = i + 1
    return factors


start_at = 1
end_at = 9
total = 9

r = range(start_at, end_at+1)

# create the tuples we look for, smaller number first - set so no duplicates
tupls = set( (a,b) if a<b else (b,a) for a in r for b in r if a+b == total)

for n in tupls:
    a,b = n
    f_a = set(factors(a))
    f_b = set(factors(b)) 

    # if either set contains the same value, the f_a & f_b will be truthy
    # so not coprime - hence skip it
    if f_a & f_b:
        continue
    print(n)
```

Output:

```
(2, 7)
(1, 8)
(4, 5)
```

Comment: Can you just make a count in it. Because for big numbers in this code i  need to count the pairs manually. I just want the count of pairs at last.

Comment: @Ravi if you are not able to adapt this code to count how many pairs got found, this solution is probably too advanced for you?